# print date in format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD without using JODA time or Apache fast date format

Tags: java

Can anyone help me to print date in the format below

```
 2016-11-22T14:52:17+05:30
```

without using JODA Time and apache fast date format.

Comment: [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: You don't need YODA time. Seriously, were are you getting your information from....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").format(new Date()));
```

or in Java8 [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").format(ZonedDateTime.now()));
```

Comment: Thanks @Jens I was struggling from an hour

Comment: @RajendraGupta You are welcome